# Postgres: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "int"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting the below error for the following Block-

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "int"
>
> Position: 14

**BLOCK**

```
declare id int;
    col_1 int; 
    col_1_input int = '21bb232s-3r22-8ns1-ad31-2f78c1c52b7a'; 
    audit_datetime timestamp(3);
    audit_datetime_input timestamp(3) = '1612-09-10 12:02:20';
    audit_action varchar(100);
```

Kindly help me in pointing my mistake.

Comment: v_col_1_input int = '21bb232s-3r22-8ns1-ad31-2f78c1c52b7a';  It is impossible

Comment: Please show us your complete function or procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the types like `smallint`, `integer`, `bigint` and `int` store whole numbers, that is, numbers without fractional components, of various ranges. Attempts to store values outside of the allowed range will result in an error.

You add a text in a `int` value and this is not allowed:

```
v_col_1_input int = '21bb232s-3r22-8ns1-ad31-2f78c1c52b7a';
```

Second to avoid the error you should add `$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql` to your code:

```
DO $$
declare 
...
begin
...
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```